# Expected a colon error issues

Tags: c

Having a hard time figuring out why I am getting a expected a ';' after the function parseString.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct Integer50
{
// a dynamically allocated array to hold a 50
// digit integer, stored in reverse order
int *digits;
} Integer50;

main() {
    Integer50 * parseString(char * str)
    { //error is on this colon
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have a function inside another function.

Comment: Because `Integer50 * parseString(char * str)` is a statement and a statement needs to end with a semi-colon?

Comment: Did you maybe mean to have the prototype in the main, rather than the actual code of the function?

Comment: And by the way your declaration of `main` is not standard compliant - it should be `int main()`

Comment: ah, thanks. And I was over here pulling my hair out.

Comment: @UnholySheep That is not standard compliant either in C, it should be `int main(void)`

Comment: @ErikW It is. If it's in a function _definition_, `()` is equivalent to `(void)`.

Comment: @ErikW: It is a compliant legacy actually. It is an obsolecent feature and (hopefully) removed with the next release in favour of prototype-style declarators.

Comment: @PSkocik It is sllowed, but obsolecent. See ^

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
main() {
    Integer50 * parseString(char * str)
    { //error is on this colon
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Should be replaced by:

```
Integer50 * parseString(char * str)
{ //error is on this colon
    return NULL;
} 

int main() {
    //If you need to call that `parseString` function call it here
}
```

So, C doesn't support function inside function. `main` is a function and `parseString` is another function. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest functions in C (though you can declare them inside a nested scope).

You will need to move:

```
Integer50 * parseString(char * str)
{ //error is on this colon
    return NULL;
}
```

to the file scope.